# Speedup animation cycles rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I have a relatively complex scene (with a lot of particles and geometry) and would like to rendee a long animation sequence from it. Right now, the only animation is the camera following a path around the scene. There would be trees moving in the wind (using spaling addon) but only after I can speed things up, so not at this moment.

I realise that before each frame in a sequence can be rendered, blender has to load every objects into memory, and that is the most time consuming process. The rendering itself does not take long, only 20 seconds (compare to 5.30 mins of loading and calculating) for VGA image size (with small CPU render title). I cannot use GPU because the high amount of geometry and object couldn't be loaded into GPU memory.

Besides reducing number of bouncing and sampling, I don't know if is there any other ways to speed up rendering, especially for animation. Somehow we can preload or prevent blender from loading everything all over again?

Comment: could you probably reduce the amount of geometry? Use unsubdivided Icospheres for round particles and do not too much subdividing in your object and you should be fine I guess. One other thing If you are using Mesh Generating Modifiers you can apply them so the calculation is done only once and not every frame.

Comment: I am using quite a lot of subdivision and sub-surface for different types of terrains (pebbles, concrete etc.) as well as particle systems (mainly for grass and leaves). The scene is large (around 20x20 to 30x30m that's why it becomes so bulky. I am not quite sure how much time consuming these subdivision and particles introduce (subsurface render is 3) but as I need the terrains to be as close to reality as possible (this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE), isn't it the only choice. Not sure if I can omit the displacement and go safe with just pure material option?

Comment: I found this one to have good tricks : https://youtu.be/dFdaoxcnvCc

Comment: FYI, Animation Node addon allows to calculate the distance from objects to the camera and to drive data path. So for instance, you can lower the subsurface level depending on this distance.